# Adding rows with excel countif condition before the headline row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

So I have this pandas dataframe (after pivot action):

[image]

I'd like to add in the first 2 rows a countif statements, first 1 is countif value is 0 and the second is count if value >0 which will give me the result:

[image]

Note that to get the dataframe I use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['patient_id', 'id', 'date', 'num', 'num_valid', 'db_valid']
df = df.pivot(index='id', columns='date')['num_valid']
```

The end result is exported to excel:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('report') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='report')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use 'openpyxl' for this.
After creating the excel file with pandas.ExcelWriter, open it with openpyxl, add row as needed with '.insert_rows' and then add value to each cell.
The countif calculations made prehand in the code rather in the excel itself.

Not the most elegant solution but it works.